# How do I let users edit the account their logged into in ruby on different pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, editing

I get the following error, Couldn't find User with 'id'=

I have this in my `Users_Controller`,

```
def edit
    @user = @signed_in_user 
end
```

This is in my `routes.rb`,

```
root 'welcome#welcome'

  get 'login' => 'sessions#login', :as => :login 

  get 'profile' => 'users#profile', :as => :profile

  post 'logging/user' => 'sessions#create'  

  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout 

  get 'about' => 'about'

  resources :users

  get 'register' => 'users#new', :as => :register

  get 'edit' => 'users#edit', :as => :edit
```

This is in my `application_controller.rb`,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_user 
  protected 
  def set_user 
    unless session[:user_id] == nil 
        @signed_in_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
  end
end
```

This is in my Users_Controller

Here is my code from my User_Controller on creating the account

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
  def profile 
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == ""
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 

  end 

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = @signed_in_user 

  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :age)
    end
end
```

And this is the link that I use for my HTML,

```
<li role="presentation"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_path %></li>
```

Comment: Check what value does `session[:user_id]` have in the application controller.

Comment: I'm just gonna comment on this now, I did the debug thing. I am not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have posted a answer for you which would help to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

1. So, to start, a good practice when you get an 'Couldn't find' message is to check what instance variables are in your view.

So in a view, just type: `<%= @user_id %>` and see if anything shows up on your page, thus indicating if any user is even present!  The other problem is that your instance variable might be `<%= user.id %>` but I am not sure as I can't see your code and how the user is stored in the database.

2. Second if you run rake routes, you generally find that the edit path will have a URI pattern like: `"/edit(.:format)"`, meaning the route need `"edit_path(@user.id)"` rather than just `"edit_path"`.

Let me know if this leads you anywhere or you have further questions and I hope I can answer them!

===========

Additional info:

Well without more code to look at, I would provide a few more suggestions...The goal is to have the `<%= @user.id %>` (or user_id) show up on the page somehow, thus telling you it is available.

1. The set_user method is an instance method, not a class method.  To make it a class method, try `def self.set_user`.  This invokes the method of the instance on the controller, thus making it a class method.
2. Make sure you have a session object to use.  In the routes, it looks like  post logging/user might be creating the session, but I am not sure.
3. Keep the edit_path(@user.id) or however the id is stored for the user as the route rather than just edit_path.  I am pretty sure if you run 'rake routes', it will tell you that an additional variable needs to be passed for the link to work

Comment: Okay, I am not seeing any user id come up with both of those codes you gave me. Also, I added the change to my edit_path and still the same error. If I can post anything else from my code to help please let me know.

Comment: Do you have code for creating the user in your User Controller?  So when you create a user, are you actually creating one and having a successful redirect?  Also, I would recommend using a gem like 'devise'.  Rails is awesome because there are so many things people have done for you.  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: you will never get `@user_id` as there is no such defined variable. It will always give null value.

Comment: Ill update my question with that information. Also, Deep... I'm not sure how you're helping much because I don't know what your comment means to me.

Comment: Do you know about debugging the application? Just use `byebug/debugger/pry` or any of these depends on rails version. And check what your `session[:user_id]` gives. If it is giving null value then that is the problem. Just correct it and your problem will be resolved. And if there is any other issue then edit the question with that.

Comment: I seriously can't get any debugging gems to work. Is there a pre-installed one I can use? Nothing has been helping me.

Comment: Which rails version are you on?

Comment: This is in my Gemfile gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

Comment: Use `byebug`. Here is the link: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug add this to gem file and run `bundle install` and then use it and test the application. And may be the gem file already contains `byebug` in the development group check it first. To use it just write `byebug` where ever you want to add a breakpoint.

Comment: Well, I've done so and in my console their is an arrow point at a specific line in my application. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Use the gem `byebug` Here is the link: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug. You get this error while the edit page or where ever you are getting the error write in the action `byebug`. As you have mentioned in the console it shows a arrow pointing at a specific line in the application, the last line should appear as this `(byebug)`, here write the variable in which you are getting the user id. If we take an example of your application controller in the `set_user` method:

```
  def set_user
    byebug
    unless session[:user_id] == nil 
        @signed_in_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
  end
```

In the console after `(byebug)` write `session[:user_id]` so this will give you the value of the `session[:user_id]`. So if this is null then you have a problem here or just follow the same procedure to check anywhere else.

Also there is one more thing you can do to learn is just create a new project or use the existing one and generate a scaffold which will give you options of show, edit, index. It will generate all the views, controller code, migration and everything. You can do that like this:

```
rails generate scaffold User email:string password:string
```

You can add more fields if you want. And then in your application just visit http://localhost:[port_no]/users which will by default take you to index page where you can add new users, edit existing ones. This will teach you about everything. It would be like a reference code for you. Read more at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate

And being more specific to users only there is a gem named [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) which will give you all the required things like sign_in, sign_up, session_management for users. Hope these things help you with your issue.

Edit:

Here is a very good tutorial link which will help you: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-updating_users

Comment: I did what you said, There was no issue in my application controler but I did it in my Users_controller and I only got a return of "NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `session' for UsersContr
oller:Class
nil"

Comment: just try the gem or scaffold which might help you. Also please update the question with the full users controller. As you should get the session in all controllers. Don't know why you are not getting it.

Comment: I updated the question with the full User_controller

Comment: added a link in the answer which will help you